# passing formname as an argument in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a project named as Masterforms which contains many forms.

I have to pass that formname as an argument to a function i.e

Masterforms contains suppliers,items,jobs etc forms.....

I called a method `openform(masterforms.suppliers)`

defintion is

```
Private Sub openform(ByVal formname as  // Form)
```

Comment: You are passing the form and not form name. Do you require the form or formname?

Comment: Can you post your code? I am unclear as to whether you are trying to pass the form name (which would be a string" or an instance of the form in question. Please post the OpenForm method, and an example of the client code you are using to call it. There is likely a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a specific form to show just by instantiating it and call a show method.

like this :

```
Dim form as New Form2() 
form.Show
```

or you can call

```
form.ShowDialog()
```

if you want the form to open in a modal way. If that's what you want...

If you just want the form name, you can pass`form.Name` as a String parameter to a method, and that'll use the `Name` property of your form. (Make sure you have initialized it first though).

Hope it helps you.